# C++ clarification of "return"

Tags: c++, return

**Homework, just advise please**

Apparently my idea of what returning something in a method does is wrong.  I'm trying to write methods for getting derivatives of numbers and operations.  So far I just wanted to get the derivative of a non-negative number that isn't accompanied with an "x" (result should be zero no matter what value is given).

The code is pretty long and needs to be cleaned up so I'll just include the method, the call, and what I'm getting.

Method:

```
int noXDerivative(int tempInt, string tempX)
{
    if (tempX == "")
    {
        tempInt = 0;
    }
    return tempInt;
}

void getDerivatives(int tempInt, string tempX, int tempInt2, string tempX2, char tempOperator)
{
    noXDerivative(tempInt, tempX);
    noXDerivative(tempInt2, tempX2);
}
```

The call:

```
getDerivatives(tempNumInt, tempNumX, tempNum2Int, tempNum2X, expression[iterator]);
```

I also called the "noXDerivative" directly to see what would happen but the result didn't change.  The test I'm running right now is "5 + 6" (tempNumInt is 5 and tempNum2Int is 6).  I keep getting 11 when I need to get 0 (again, there are no "x"s).  I was hoping that if I put tempNumInt as one of the parameters it would be changed from 5 to 0 within the noXDerivative method but it doesn't.  How do I correct this?

Comment: Consider reading a basic book on C++ first. It seems to me that you are wasting your time coding difficult stuff in a language you don't yet understand.

Comment: hint: you're passing tempInt by value, if you change it in noXDerivative the change won't be passed back to the caller.

Comment: How do you know what you are "getting"?

Comment: @Alexandre Thank you for your suggestion.  I actually did that when I was learning C#, took me a while and by the time I started coding I found out that I learned more from asking the community than I did reading a book.  I guess it's just how I learn but I do appreciate your comment and I agree that the best way to start is to read books.

Comment: Multivariable calculus over integers?

Comment: @Jesse: I owe you a little explanation: in C#, you can pass objects to functions and expect them to have changed when the function return. In C++ you have to use **pointers** or **references** for this. Since those concepts are basic to the language, they are better explained in books (or by searching those terms online now you know them).

Comment: @Potatoswatter The assignment is just for basic derivatives.  The hardest it gets with with functions and exponents.  The professor doesn't require (or want) us to use doubles or floats or anything other than ints

Comment: @Alexandre Thank you for the explanation.  I will look up those terms since you've mentioned them.  I sincerely appreciate the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to say that I don't understand what it is that you're trying to do.

Nevertheless, to achieve your goal of modifying `tempInt` inside `getDerivatives()`, you can either do:

```
tempInt = noXDerivative(tempInt, tempX);
```

Or, you can modify the `noXDerivative()` function to take its argument *by reference*, rather than *by value*:

```
int noXDerivative(int &tempInt, string tempX)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Jesse: I'm glad that helped.  However, if you're having trouble understanding how to return values from functions, I suggest you take @Alexandre C's advice above, and find a good beginner's C++ book to learn the basics.

Comment: Whoa, sorry that my comment got deleted, I was reading everything else and didn't see it on here, I probably clicked the "x" by accident or something.  Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

return does just that--it *returns* a value. It doesn't change the value passed in. If I understand your code correctly, I bet that if you had something like

`int result1 = noXDerivative(tempInt, tempX)`

result1 would hold the value 0. Mind you, tempInt and tempInt2 in getDerivatives won't be modified then, so you'll need to figure that out...

Answer (score 0):

well, not a lot to "advise". The problem here is that when a routine `returns` a value, the call must be used as a left hand value.

```
tempInt = noXDerivative(tempInt, tempX);
```

You will not modify the value of tempInt otherwise, at least with the current signature of your routine. You are passing tempInt as an argument by value with that call, and any modifications you perform to tempInt will occur on the local stack frame of that routine.